# how to skip every other iteration

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to output a range of numbers, and break them out into separate rows:

```
1: ABC-1 - ABC-100
2: ABC-101 - ABC-200
3: ABC-201 - ABC-300
4: ABC-301 - ABC-400
5: ABC-401 - ABC-500
6: ABC-501 - ABC-600
7: ABC-601 - ABC-700
8: ABC-701 - ABC-800
9: ABC-801 - ABC-900
10: ABC-901 - ABC-1000
```

I did that with this:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int order = 1000;
        int increment = 100;
        int rows = order / increment;
        string prefix = "ABC-";
        int startNumber = 1;
        int startRows = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++)
        {
            int rowIdx = startRows + (i - 1);
            int startIdx = startNumber + (increment * (i - 1));
            int endIdx = increment * i;

            System.Console.WriteLine($"{rowIdx}: {prefix}{startIdx} - {prefix}{endIdx}", i);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to iterate every other row number however, like this:

```
1A: ABC-1 - ABC-100
1B: ABC-101 - ABC-200
2A: ABC-201 - ABC-300
2B: ABC-301 - ABC-400
3A: ABC-401 - ABC-500
3B: ABC-501 - ABC-600
4A: ABC-601 - ABC-700
4B: ABC-701 - ABC-800
5A: ABC-801 - ABC-900
5B: ABC-901 - ABC-1000
```

It took me a few hours (trying not to look at tutorials/docs) to get the range to iterate, but getting the rows to "skip" stumped me completely.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into C#'s Remainder operator - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators also called Modulo: https://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo

```
        int order = 1000;
        int increment = 100;
        int rows = order / increment;
        string prefix = "ABC-";
        int startNumber = 1;
        int startRows = 1;

        int linecounter = 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++)
        {
            int rowIdx = startRows + (i - 1);
            int startIdx = startNumber + (increment * (i - 1));
            int endIdx = increment * i;
            string linePrefix = (i % 2 == 0) ? $"{linecounter++}B" : $"{linecounter}A";
            
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{linePrefix}: {prefix}{startIdx} - {prefix}{endIdx}", i);
        }
```

Working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/liI2Jh

Comment: thank you, remainder/modulo looks very powerful! And your explanation makes sense too with "{linecounter++}B" incrementing... very nice.  

One thing I didn't understand was the [? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), but that appears to be a boolean expression that's either going to return A or B.   

So the final solution was to use the remainder % operator with i, and then use the  ? operator to determine the boolean of A or B.   

Great stuff and thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
        int order = 1000;
        int increment = 100;
        int rows = order / increment;
        string prefix = "ABC-";
        int startNumber = 1;
        int startRows = 1;
        string skip = "A";
        for (int i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++)
        {
            int rowIdx = startRows + (i - 1);
            int startIdx = startNumber + (increment * (i - 1));
            int endIdx = increment * i;

            System.Console.WriteLine($"{(rowIdx+1)/2}{skip}: {prefix}{startIdx} - {prefix}{endIdx}", i);
            skip = skip == "A" ? "B" : "A";
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @hossein, your solution worked great but I didn't understand it until I read about the ? operator. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ringthane C# includes a decision-making operator ?: which is called the conditional operator or ternary operator. It is the short form of the if else conditions.